# Is it possible, with jQuery, to "intercept" two actions?

Tags: jquery

Strange title... I've this function:

```
$('#text').keyup(function() {
    // stuff here
}
```

i would "reuse" all my code in "stuff here" also in other event

```
$('#previousSms').change(function() {
    // same stuff here
}
```

to have a similar scenario (pseudocode)

```
if
 $('#previousSms').change OR $('#text').keyup
```

impossibile?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `on()`:

```
$('#text, #previousSms').on('keyup change', function(){
    // do stuff here
});
```

If, on the other hand, you need to use the same function depending on the event on a particular element:

```
$('selectorForCommonAncestor').on('keyup change', '#text, #previousSms', function(e){
    var eName = e.type,
        elID = this.id;
    if (eName == 'keyup' && elID == 'text') {
        // do stuff for keyup event on #text
    }
    else if (eName == 'change' && elID == 'previousSms') {
        // do stuff for change event on #previousSms
    }
});
```

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: This is what should be used, the other answers work, but are just silly.

Comment: I'll work on this solution. Thank you! @VictorKilo: i don't think btw that others answer are silly. Other answer focused correctly on create a function, and surely are right also the other ;) So i make respect for all people that gave me a (correct) answer ;)

Comment: The question asked for something that would handle "`$('#previousSms').change` OR `$('#text').keyup`". This answer also handles `$('#previousSms').keyup` and `$('#text').change`.

Comment: @David Thomas - No disrespect intended! To me, silly is a very light term.
@JasonP - the `.on()` function addresses `OR`. The user will not have to both have keyup and change at the same time.  It accepts either trigger. This answer does what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function and use it for each event:

```
$('#text').keyup(myFunction);
$('#previousSms').change(myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
    //do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

```
function something (event) { /* stuff */ }

$('#text').keyup(something);
$('#previousSms').change(something);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect job for a function.

```
$('#text').keyup(doStuff);

$('#previousSms').change(doStuff);

function doStuff(){
//same stuff
}
```